# Determine if Optional Parameter was passed in WCF Soap Service

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I am trying to determine if optional parameters were passed to my WCF service.  For example assume I have a simple input object defined as follows.

```
[DataContract]
public class TestObject
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired=false)]
    public int OptionalIntegerField { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public bool OptionalBooleanField { get; set; }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public string OptionalStringField { get; set; }
}
```

And a service contract defined as

```
[OperationContract(Name = "TestMethod")]
void TestMethod(TestObject obj);
```

If I have TestMethod defined as

```
    public void TestMethod(TestObject obj)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(obj.OptionalBooleanField);
        Debug.WriteLine(obj.OptionalIntegerField);
        Debug.WriteLine(obj.OptionalStringField);
    }
```

My problem is that if I make a SOAP call to TestMethod with no input parameters specified, OptionalIntegerField and OptionalBooleanField (being Value types) are set to their default values (0 and false).  I need to determine whether or not an optional Parameter was passed in.

My question is what is the appropriate way to deal with this? I was thinking about making my OptionalIntegerField and OptionalBooleanField nullable types, but I am not sure if that is the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your reference types are also using the concept of null in the same way, where null means that a value is not present, nullable value types are a perfectly acceptable way of indicating that possibility for value type members.

Comment: I agree that your response is the acceptable answer to this specific question. But making nullable types is the only solution to such a problem? Do you know of any other solution?

Comment: You don't have to use a nullable type, but if you don't then you need some other common designation of a missing value. You could use the default value to mean that it's missing, but then that disallows the default as a valid value. Alternately, you could add custom serialization to your contract objects to set missing values to a default "missing" value of your choice. The question, though, is why you would want to do that. If there's a reason that a nullable value type wouldn't work for your situation, I'd suggest you ask a new question on Stack Overflow about that.